# Issue with jQuery class toggling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some list items. 
Followings are some scenarios:

1. If I click any list item it become selected and add a class .slected
2. If I click another list item previous list become unselected and new list become selected
3. If I click the list item which already been selected it become unselected

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/has9L9Lh/40/)**

Those scenarios working perfectly. But problem occurs when I press the Edit link. I don't wanted to Unselect during Edit mode. It should remain selected during I perform edit actions.

How I can do this matching those 3 conditions ? what wrong I am doing here ? Any help with this will save my day. Thanks in advance.

**JS**

```
$("body").on('click', '.list-group-item', function() {  

    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
       $(this).removeClass('selected');
     } else {
      $(".list-group-item").removeClass('selected');
       $(this).addClass('selected');
     }


});
```

Comment: Off topic: See this fiddle for a simpler approach to the `list-group-item` click function: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/has9L9Lh/41

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("body").on('click', '.list-group-item', function(ev) {    
    var target = ev.target; // Topmost clicked element
    if(!$(target).is(".btn")){ // If click wasn't on a button
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
    }       
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_abl/1cuwk5jr/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add the line

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

as follows:

```
$(".btn-link").click(function () {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent('.view-mode').hide();
    $(this).parent('.view-mode').siblings('.edit-mode').show();
});
```

Comment: event.stopPropagation();
Using this does not let me doing other operation like if I use Bootstrap dropdown it will not open.